# Excel Macro to separate date into year month week

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a really difficult time with this excel table and was trying to use VBA as well as Excel functions to get the date formatted into Year, Month, Week but I keep running into issues.

I have the below input:[image]

The reason Column1 looks so odd is because I was TRYING to use =MONTH([Date]) but it looks all weird and doesn't sort into the month or week it is supposed to.

Below is the expected outcome if everything were to work.

[image]

So using the Date column I want to generate 3 columns: Year, Month, Week

Any idea if I am doing something wrong in excel or if there is an easy way to do this in VBA?

Comment: you should chagne format of your column: http://content.gcflearnfree.org/topics/175/3_number_format_box.png

Comment: Check the formatting on Column1, it might be that it is set to date, which would indeed format the number '12' to '01/12/1900'. 
It seems you are getting what you want, you just need to look for the excel formatting of your cells.
Also update your question with the code you used so we can also take a look at that if necessary.

Comment: @simoco thank you but now what can I to get the 3 columns? I still have to split this up so should I use VBA and use Split and then do some code to create the week number?

Comment: what week number you need? week of year or week of month?

Comment: Now my Date column is in the format 19-Dec-2013 so should I Split using VBA and do the rest of 3 columns myself? Week of month..Maybe using the Split function I would have 4 if statements since each month has 4 weeks and using the day I can classify which week it is of the month. Would there be an easier solution?

Comment: for week you can use this formula: `=WEEKNUM([@Date])-WEEKNUM(EOMONTH([@Date],-1)+1)`. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the date in **A2** , in **E2** enter:

`=A2`  and format as "yyyy"

In **F2** enter:

`=A2`  and format as "mm-mmmm"

In **G2** enter:

```
="Week " & ROUNDUP(DAY(A2)/7,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where the issue is but the following formulae will give you year, month, and day. Where a1 contains a date

```
=year(a1)
=month(a1)
=day(a1)
```

Of course if you want the month to show the month in words rather than a number you can format the cell as custom and then mmm

Answer (score 0):

- Formula for year: `=YEAR([@Date])`
- Formula for month: `=MONTH([@Date]) & "-" & TEXT([@Date],"mmmm")`
- Formula for week: `="Week " & WEEKNUM([@Date],2)-WEEKNUM(EOMONTH([@Date],-1)+1,2)+1`

and use appropriate format for each column.

[image]

Comment: user3438716, I've updated screenshot - last column is not required

Comment: can you explain please what column you need to exclude or what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right formula the only thing amiss is your column formatting as it is correctly pointed out in the comments. Follow these steps to get the desired formatting

1. Select the column and right click Click 'Format Cell'
2. In the'Number' tab select 'Custom' in the category list
3. Enter 'mm - mmmm' as the type.

You should get '12 - December'